# Clion strange code indentation

Tags: c++, clion

I am using `Predefined style -> Allman braces` and this is the strange behavior I get:

```
// this looks good 
int edges = 0;

long        variable_2 = 0;
AnotherLong obj        = 0;


// this looks bad      way off
int edges              = 0;

long        variable_1;
long        variable_2 = 0;
AnotherLong obj        = 0;
```

The variables should be grouped in columns, however an empty line should indicate a new "block" of code, right ? On the first case `int edges = 0;` is aligned fine, why not in the second case ? How can I fix that ?

**Edit:** Created a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6223)

Comment: seems like that indentation style is aligning the '=' signs; which it is doing perfectly; I see no problem. Your variable_1 isn't initialize...

Comment: @ChrisMaes My `variable_1` is perfect. Look at the variable `int edges = 0;`

Comment: Are you certain that there are no differences between the two other than the addition of `variable_1`? E.g., is it possible that in the second case you've got a trailing space on the line, or a carriage return in a file that mostly has just newlines for line endings, or something like that that CLion might interpret as not-an-empty-line? You could check this by deleting the blank line and then adding a new definitely blank line.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I am 100% sure. I just went and retyped the whole thing from scratch in [here](https://i.gyazo.com/e0f00d5bb4e2cba3c3ed6d3926f2b37a.png) after I saw your comment. Try it.

Comment: Sounds like a CLion bug to me, then. (Though the CLion docs aren't all that explicit about how alignment is done -- so it's not exactly a bug in the sense of nonconformance to documented behaviour, but it doesn't seem like what anyone would want.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yea, it is pretty frustrating. I will try and see where I can report this bug.

Comment: Here, I think: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP